# Algorithm to find a best match for a search query

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy

I came across a problem for which I don't know the specific name and could not find any papers or tools.

The problem is the following one. Let's consider I have a database with cars, each of them has the attributes for the year when they were built, which manufacturer built it, color and so and and the value of this car.

Now a user can give a search query, f.e. "mustang 1998 red 2000€" and I want to find the beste matches to this query.

I was thinking about a score system for each entry, based on the attributes and how much they differ from the users search, but here I lack knowledge.

Are there any articles or tools I can read or test which provide this kind of function?

Comment: This looks like a text similarity problem in Natural Language Processing. Could you please paste a few examples within which the response content exists for the given query. This can be investigated for a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The user is supposed to enter queries like 'webdeveloper Munich 200 employees'. The system then should give similar options from a database. Could you explain a little more why you would use a natural language procession tool? This option didn't even come to my mind :)